# CvxOPT fails to run: _gfortran_st_write_done undefined

Tags: python, cvxopt

I am trying to get cvxopt running on a linux-ppc64 system. I had to compile and install everything, roughly in the following order, from source, without root access.

a) Python 2.7
b) BLAS, LAPACK
c) NUMPY, SCIPY
d) CVXOPT

I first installed Python, then managed to get pip running. All of my packages are in ~/local. (PYTHONUSERBASE=~/local).

I compiled BLAS, LAPACK and got those libraries into ~/local/lib. Pip manages to install numpy, scipy and cvxopt without complaining. However, on running a test cvxopt code (lp.py in the cvxopt examples directory), I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /users/home/jaikumar/.python-eggs/cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-linux-ppc64.egg-tmp/cvxopt/blas.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done
```

I checked that I have no other fortran compiler except gfortran installed on the system. libgfortran is present in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3

Could someone please let me know why the undefined symbol "_gfortran_st_write_done" is turning up and how to fix it?

Also, why does it create this temporary dir ~/.python-eggs in my home dir? Is this normal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that ~/.python-eggs is normal, because I am getting it on MAC

I am getting  undefined symbol "_gfortran_st_write_done" also on a MAC